# Should I use `suspend` keyword on functions that do not suspend coroutine inside their bodies?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I understand that the first and obvious thought is that you shouldn't do it exists but hold one for a minute.

My colleague's opinion is that you should because you could have CPU-intensive calculations but which are not suspending coroutine, but we could help the Kotlin's compiler to identify it and reschedule caller coroutine if it exists and do not "block" underlying thread.

Can someone inlight me about this topic? And if it isn't implemented yet I think that this could be a cool idea but I understand the Kotlin Coroutine's internals poorly

Comment: I think that it is a good question, but maybe a little too broad. You could try to add one or two code sample to try and focus the question around a specific use-case. In my opinion, *it depends*... coroutines will add overhead to your function. So, for any CPU intensive task that is short enough (let say less than 1 second in average), I would not make it suspendable. For longer computing flow, yes, that could be interesting, to improve overall *throughput*. Now, without measures and use-cases, however, it is difficult to provide a really good insight/advice.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there are any performance benefits of marking a function `suspend` if it doesn't suspend. It is actually the opposite. There is an overhead associated with suspend functions and it affects the performance even if not suspending.

There could be still reasons to make a function suspend even if it doesn't suspend. One example is if we expect we may like to make it suspend in the future. Then it could be a good idea to mark it as such from the beginning as doing it later is a backward incompatible change. Also, by making it suspend we can add support for cancellations and we can `yield()` from time to time to allow other tasks to jump it. It is a good idea to do this to make CPU-intensive code more coroutine-friendly.

But to be honest, I don't really understand the point about: "help the Kotlin's compiler to identify it". CPU-intensive calculations are by definition non-suspendable. Neither the Kotlin compiler nor the coroutines framework will treat the function differently only because it says "suspend". It will be executed as normal and will "block" the calling thread until computation finishes.